# How to display element between table rows?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a table that has data associated with each row.

e.g.

```
Column 1      | Column 2
Data            More Data
  Data part a     More Data part a
  Data part b     More Data part b
```

I need to display this data inbetween each row depending on what the user selects. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just place the div into another row, and toggle its visibility?

Comment: you should listen to @Teemu

Comment: you should listen to @A.O.

Comment: [Recursion](https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion)

Comment: As per @guest; http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/8QyDY/ , also check http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2Fkimiliini%2F8QyDY%2Fshow%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments by @Teemu, @A.O and @guest.

[Sample fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/8QyDY/)

Also check out validation by:

- HTML: http://validator.w3.org/ [example](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/8QyDY/show/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)
- CSS : http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Quick concept:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell1</td>
        <td>Cell2</td>
        <td>Cell3</td>
        <td>Cell4</td>
        <td>Cell5</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" id="content1">
            <div>
               Toggle able content
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
[id*=content] {
    background: #eee;
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$("input").click(function () {
    var $el = $($(this).data('href'));
    if ($el.is(":visible")) {
        $el.hide();
    } else {
        $el.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add rows for the content and put the content div in those rows. Then simply toggle the display of those rows between `none` and table-row. 
for example: css

```
.content {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
.content.collapse {
    display: none;
}
```

html

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" data-href="#content1" ></td>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td><td>10258</td><td>07/17/1996</td><td>$403.72</td>
</tr>
<tr class="content collapse" id="content1">
    <td colspan="5">
        <div>Content 1</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" data-href="#content2"></td>
    <td>Wartian Herkku</td><td>10270</td><td>08/01/1996</td><td>$1,376.00</td>
</tr>
<tr class="content collapse" id="content2">
    <td colspan="5">
        <div>Content 2</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input").click(function() {
        var contentId =this.dataset.href;
        $(contentId).toggleClass("collapse");
    });

});
```

Here's [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aneelkkhatri/N8Y6c/44/)